# Alert dialog with single choice items with subtitle

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-alertdialog

How to create that dialog for application with min SDK 16 version using standard platform. I'm try use `android.support.v7.AlertDialog`. I can create custom adapter:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(owner);
//...
builder.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(...))
```

But I think this is a bad decision.
Whether it is possible to do it somehow:

```
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, subitems...)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBAj3.png)